# At what age is a person considered to be シルバー?

Tags: words, katakana, word-usage, loanwords

I read this term in an online article and it was referring to people. I assume it means elderly people. Is there an age that one must be to use this term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to depend upon which organization or company is assigning the designation. Usually using 65 to 70 years of age as a lower threshold. This is similar to varying ages for 'senior discounts' (in the US anyways).

[Here is a page](https://overage-job.jp/blog/senior-howold/) from NTT Facilities Research, which lists a few terms regarding the elderly relative to age.

Answer (score -1):

It literally means **silver**-haired (A beautiful expression of white hair due to aging) people.

Also, this term is mostly used to sell something, so usually it means old but somewhat healthy old people, mostly 65 to 75 years old in Japan IMO.